# Token authentication with openstack for many clients

Tags: node.js, authentication, pkgcloud

My question is that is possible to create client **only base on the token** in pkgcloud library for nodejs.

Because what I see there is that straight-forward approach:

```
var rackspace = pkgcloud.storage.createClient({
    provider: 'openstack',
    username: 'your-user-name',
    password: 'your-password',
    authUrl: '...'
  });
```

which allow to create client by using username, password credentials. 
But let say that there is many clients and I would like to authenticate them once and after use only token to make operation on object store like allowing that OpenStack. I don't want to keep their credentials on my server side only their tokens. So from other side how could I make operations (like upload, list, create containers etc...) by using pkgcloud with only tokens for my authenticated clients ?

So scenario looks the following:

1. I authenticate user1 by username, password
2. I receive token1 from OpenStack for user1
3. I store that token1 in my database
4. I authenticate user2 by username, password
5. I receive token2 from OpenStack for user2
6. I store that token2 in my database
7. Now I want to use that token1 from user1 to make next operation (like list containers) on object store

Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

The same question as referred by someone and a work around was suggested by Ken Perkins. I am not sure if we have a permanent solution to this.

[https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/issues/352]